# Https not working on EC2 node.js custom domain

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, netlify

I have a Node.js + Express app running on AWS EC2 with Elastic IP assigned to it. I have a website hosted from Netlify.

I have configured SSL on Netlify so my website is secured and so are its sub-domains.

```
*.mywebsite.com
```

Now I want to redirect the user to my node.js application when they go to
web.mywebsite.com.

To do this I created a new CNAME entry in the DNS setting looking like this:

```
Name: web.mywebsite.com
TTL: 3600 seconds
Type: CNAME
Value: ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

On my EC2 instance I am redirecting the traffic coming to port 443 to port 8000 (where my Node.js app is running)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

I also did the following for testing purposes:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

In my EC2 security group I have given the following rules

[image]

Now the problem is if I go to

http://web.mywebsite.com it opens my web application (I dont want this as its on unsecure channel)

If I do https://web.mywebsite.com it does not open the page (or web app).

Any idea what is going on? I already have the SSL running on all wildcard domains so technically it should work.

Comment: Where did you upload the certificate?

Comment: On Netlify I have enabled automatic TLS certificates with Let’s Encrypt

Comment: If you didn't upload certificate to EC2 instance and did not configure SSL termination on the instance then you can't expect your EC2 instance to receive and be able to process HTTPS traffic.

Comment: So any idea how I can do it? Do I have to reissue SSL certificate again for my sub-domain?

Comment: This is not so simple. Just having certificate means nothing, you need to configure some SSL termination point along the traffic path. Be it CloudFront, Load Balancer or the EC2 instance. The process differs depending on which path you choose. But be aware that once you terminate SSL, traffic that is sent from this point to destination will be unencrypted (unless you establish another SSL communication between those two points).

Comment: I am super confused. Can you guide me to some documentation or some example? It will really help me a lot. Also can I also use ACM to issue a new ssl certificate and assign it to my ec2? I think I had seen a tutorial somewhere about this.

Comment: Configuring SSL termination on EC2 instance is usually a pain. If you don't need end to end encryption and you are willing to pay for elastic load balancer, then the easiest way is to issue certificate through ACM, upload it to load balancer and terminate SSL there. You can't directly upload certificate from ACM to EC2 instance, you need to use some service integrated with ACM for that, such as load balancer or CloudFront. Here is link (ALB SSL termination) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html